# fsevents causes Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�'

Tags: webpack, next.js

I am using `next.js` and I get:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I tried almost everything, most recently, to `package.json`, I added:

```
    "optionalDependencies": {
        "fsevents": "^2.1.3"
    }
```

In `next.config.js`, I have:

```
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

module.exports = withPlugins([
    withCSS,
    withImages,
]
```

Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I fixed it in my VS Code extension by adding:

```
{
  test: /.node$/,
  loader: 'node-loader',
}
```

to the `module.rules` in `webpack.config.js`
and adding:

```
    "node-loader": "^1.0.1",
```

to the `devDependencies` in `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

Try check what encoding used in fsevents.node
I was getting similar exception. Problem was in UTF-16 encoding of file. Changed to UTF-8 and it did help.